# Getting part of the page to display updated data in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue to create a page where I list all users and if I click on the edit button the details of that user then gets shown
next to the list.

What I'm trying to do is, if I update a user and click save then the user details in the list needs to change.
The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to get the details to change in the list after I've saved.

My vue

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-sm mt-2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="user in displayAllUsers">
                                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @click="manageUser(user)">Edit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5" v-if="user != null">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title mb-0">Manage {{ user.name }}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" v-model="user.name"> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button @click="updateUser()"class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        components: {

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                users: [],
                user: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            displayAllUsers(){
                return this.users;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            manageUser(user){
                axios.get('/admin/user/'+user.id).then((response) => {
                    this.user = response.data.user;
                });
            },
            updateUser(){
                axios.put('/admin/user/'+this.user.id, {
                    name: this.user.name
                }).then((response) => {
                    this.users = response.data.user;
                });
            }

        },

        mounted() {
            axios.get('/admin/users').then((response) => {
                this.users = response.data.users;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if you found my answer useful remember to upvote and check the answer as the right one :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

1. The first is to run this code at the end of the `updateUser` method:

```
axios.get('/admin/users').then((response) => {
    this.users = response.data.users;
});
```

2. The second is to use a state manager like [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

The first scenario will fetch again your users data from the remote API and will update your view with all your users.

With the second scenario, you will handle your application state way much better than just using the `data` attribute of your page module, but in the background, it is more or less the same as the first solution I suggest.

To update the current user only in the table you could do something like that at the end of the `updateUser` method:

```
let userIdx = -1;

for(let idx = 0, l = this.users.length; idx < l; idx++) {
    if ( this.user.id === this.users[idx].id ) {
        userIdx = idx;
        break;
    }
}

if ( -1 !== userIdx ) {
    this.users[userIdx] = this.user;
    this.user = {};
}
```

---

Other than your problem, it seems like you don't need this code:

```
computed: {
    displayAllUsers(){
        return this.users;
    }
},
```

You could remove this code, and instead use this code in the HTML part:

`<tr v-for="user in users">`

Comment: If I add the `axios.get()` then wouldn't that bring in my list again? Isn't there a way to only update that specific user?

Comment: Yes, always there is one way. One option is to iterate over your users in the `data` to find the index of the current user, using his ID, and then do in place changes.  The other way is as I told you in my answer to use the Vuex.

Comment: then how would I do the first option then? I can filter and get that specific user like this `let user = this.users.filter(a => a.id == response.data.user.id);`

Answer (score 0):

For your updateUser function you could just return the modified user in the same format that you have for all the users in you user list and update the user by index. This is presuming that the user you want to update is in the users array to start with.

```
updateUser() {
    axios.put('/admin/user/'+this.user.id, {
        name: this.user.name
    }).then((response) => {
        const updatedUser = response.data.user;

        // Find the index of the updated user in the users list
        const index = this.users.findIndex(user => user.id === updatedUser.id);

        // If the user was found in the users list update it
        if (index >= 0) {
            // Use vue set to update the array by index and force an update on the page
            this.$set(this.users, index, updatedUser);
        }
    });
}
```

This could be a good starting point.

Unrelated Note:

You can add your mounted function code to its own method, for example

```
getUsers() {
    axios.get('/admin/users').then((response) => {
         this.users = response.data.users;
    });
}
```

then

```
mounted() {
    this.getUsers()
}
```

this makes it a little cleaner and easier if you ever need to get the users again (example: if you start having filters the user can change)

As it could get more complex vuex would be a great addition.